# Get emails with imap_tools with python

Tags: python, imap-tools

I want to receive all the today's email texts from a specific sender and put them into a list from outlook with imap-tools

I have made the following function but the problem is that it doesn't retrieve emails from 12:00AM - 12:00PM, is there any way to specify the hours for getting the proper messages?

```
def get_emails(username, password, sender):
    from imap_tools import MailBox, A

    emails = []

    with MailBox('outlook.office365.com').login(username, password, 'INBOX') as mailbox:
        for msg in mailbox.fetch(
                A(
                    A(date_gte=datetime.date.today()),  # get the today's emails
                    A(from_=sender),         # from the specific senderEmailAddress
                ),
                mark_seen = True
            ):
            if msg.subject == "Subject":
                emails.append(msg.text)
        return emails
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `date` ([`imap_tools` documentation](https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/#search-criteria)):

```py
from imap_tools import MailBox, A

def get_emails(username, password, sender):
    emails = []

    with MailBox('outlook.office365.com').login(login_name, login_password, 'INBOX') as mailbox:
        for msg in mailbox.fetch(
                A(date=datetime.date.today(), from_=sender),
                mark_seen = True
            ):
            if msg.subject == "Subject":
                emails.append(msg.text)
        return email
```

Comment: This does exactly the same job....

Comment: @David this retrieves all the emails from today; not from the future. This guarantees the hours will be of those you specified, because it is today.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me, I have also noticed that when I try to print out the date each email was received e.g: msg.date I am getting wrong date

Comment: @David could you give us the output of `datetime.date.today()` and `datetime.datetime.utcnow().astimezone().tzinfo`?

Comment: >> datetime.datetime.utcnow().astimezone().tzinfo datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800), 'GTB Daylight Time') 

>> datetime.date.today(): datetime.date(2022, 9, 25)

Answer (score 0):

There is no filter by time in IMAP, only by date.

Filter by time on client.